# In C#, what is the difference between comparing two dates using tick and just as it is

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm new to C#. I was going through some code written by someone who worked on my project earlier when I came across this:

```
if (olderTime.happenedWhen.Ticks > happenedWhen.Ticks)
{
   thisIsTrulyNew = false;
}
```

Both `olderTime.happenedWhen` and `happenedWhen` are of type `DateTime`.

Is this a more accurate way of comparing DateTime?

I know that Ticks represents 100 nano-second intervals from 00:00, January 1, 0001. But why do this sort of a comparison when I thought we could do:

```
if (olderTime.happenedWhen > happenedWhen){
   thisIsTrulyNew = false
}
```

Does the ticks comparison achieve something that the normal comparison wouldn't?

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is this a more accurate way of comparing DateTime?

Not in the slightest.  In fact, that is how the `>` operator is implemented internally.

From [the .NET Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1308):

```
public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
    return t1.InternalTicks > t2.InternalTicks;
}
```

Someone might have thought they were being clever by skipping the one line of internal code and going straight to the `Ticks` property.  In reality, the getter for `Ticks` returns `InternalTicks`, so unless it is optimized by the compiler, using the `Ticks` property adds *two* calls in order to save one call (neither of which would change the performance significantly).

Comment: Hm, but is InternalTicks different from Ticks? Update: No.

Comment: They are the same - `Ticks` just returns `InternalTicks`. Honestly, I don't see why `InternalTicks` is necessary other than to add a level of abstraction between the public property and the internal representation.

Comment: `Someone might have thought they were being clever` Another explanation might be that they weren't sure it DateTime overloaded comparison operators and used something they knew worked. They could have checked but it's such an insignificant thing that I don't know if I'd bother personally.

Answer (score 18):

The implementation of the `operator >` for `DateTime` compares the ticks too, as you can see from this disassembled code (mscorlib.dll, System.DateTime class):

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public long Ticks
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        return this.InternalTicks;
    }
}

[__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2)
{
    return t1.InternalTicks > t2.InternalTicks;
}
```

Comment: The source code for the .NET is also publicly available now. You can see DateTime.Compare here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#673a21395e1ac1ad

Answer (score 3):

The `>` operator is implemented as follows:

```
public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2)
{
   return t1.InternalTicks > t2.InternalTicks;
}
```

So it's really the same (as `Ticks` returns `InternalTicks`).

Answer (score 3):

The [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#df6b1eba7461813b) shows this:

```
    public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
        return t1.InternalTicks > t2.InternalTicks;
    }
```

Which is

```
    internal Int64 InternalTicks {
        get {
            return (Int64)(dateData & TicksMask);
        }
    }
```

Where `dateData` is set in the constructor and simply refers to `dateData = (UInt64)ticks;`and `TicksMask` is

```
private const UInt64 TicksMask = 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the same thing.
From the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1308) the `>` operator is defined as:

```
public static bool operator >(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) 
{
      return t1.InternalTicks > t2.InternalTicks;
}
```

Just for completeness, the `Ticks` property is defined as:

```
public long Ticks
{
        get 
        { 
            return InternalTicks; 
        }
}
```